# eclipse create new .properties file

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I need to create a new .properties file, when I create a new file then change its name to have .properties at the end it shows with a question mark next to the file. Any advice?

Comment: This question is quite unclear. Pls provide more info, including what you have tried.

Comment: Are you using any change management system like SubVersion or Git in your project?

Comment: Sounds like the folder is controlled by svn

Comment: sorry for the lack of clarity. Its controlled by SVN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your project is controlled by SVN, the question mark appears because it's a new file and it needs to be commited, so it's like an alert for the user to say *hey, don't forget to commit this new file*.

Don't worry about the mark, you can edit the file as long as you want.

When you commit the file to the repository, the mark will dissappear. Then, if you modify the file, an asterisk (*) mark will appear in the file saying *hey, don't forget that I've been modified and you should commit me*.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this questionmark comes from your revision control system. (like Subversion)

In that case you can open the context menu in that file and click Team/Add to repository.